# Particle segmentation in an image using opencv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

[image]

[image]

After applying filter for smoothing image and closing operation to fill in the voids and complete the open boundaries to great extent for the image shown after using canny edge detection , I have a problem in the following code which takes a certain point as an input and emit rays in all directions around the point then closes the boundary based on the average diameters of the rays measured.. so my main issue is how to show the boundaries detected in the image in white colour for each particle extracted from the image using the algorithm .. how can I enhance the efficiency for that.

I expected for the image imac when I run the code to get every particle in white color without such problems as shown in step 4 in the following image

[image]

```
    imo = im * 0
    plotpoly(polyc,imo)
    plotArea(polyc,imo)
    imf = imo*1000.0 +im
    a,imf = cv2.threshold(imf,100.0,255.0,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    imac = imac + imo
    a,imac = cv2.threshold(imac,200,255,   cv2.THRESH_BINARY);
```

I wish to be when looping in the image to get the same value for the individual particle shown in step 4